# Cannot implicitly convert 'System.TimeSpan?' to 'System.TimeSpan' with .HasValue condition

Tags: c#, .net

What I want to achieve is get the years that passed from a datetime to current datetime.

```
DateTime zeroTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan span = project.StartDate != null ? now - project.StartDate  : TimeSpan.Zero;

int years = (zeroTime + span).Year - 1;
```

`project.StartDate` is nullable, so i I tried to use conditions like `project.StartDate.HasValue`, etc. I'm still getting the error:

`Cannot implicitly convert 'System.TimeSpan?' to 'System.TimeSpan'`

What am I missing, I browsed SO, and searched on google, so please don't mark it as duplicate, as you can see I already used conditions

Comment: `-` is lifted over nullables so you need to use `Value` to use the unlifted version: `project.StartDate != null ? now - project.StartDate.Value  : TimeSpan.Zero;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work. using [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

```
TimeSpan span = (now - project.StartDate) ?? TimeSpan.Zero;
```

Comment: The parentheses that you left out in your initial version are not necessary. If you added them in for readability though, then no objection at all.

Answer (score 5):

Try (you are missing the .Value):

```
TimeSpan span= project.StartDate.HasValue? now-project.StartDate.Value:TimeSpan.Zero;
```